# Storing entire documents as node properties

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm creating a knowledge graph from text documents, This will include  document nodes.

I want to store the entire text of these documents as a node property.

Is there anything inherently wrong with this?
Would it be better to store this information elsewhere and then just store a reference to that instead?

Are there any limitations to the amount of data you should add to nodes or relationships?

Comment: How frequently will you need to access the document text?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor not very often I think, it wouldn't be a typical query to access this particular property.

Comment: Then storing it in the node itself, will be fine.

Comment: It should work, but opens the door for querying all document text. That may not be your intent _today_, but in the future someone will discover that they're able to query the entire document, and so they will. At that point, you're subjecting the graph to substring queries against arbitrary text, which will probably perform poorly. This isn't specifically the fault of the graph, but more of a yet-to-happen misuse of it. All of that to say: I wouldn't do it unless I could lock down queries against the graph. And even then, I still wouldn't do it, because someone will find a way to query it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these two options:

- Store the relationships in a graph database and the document
  information in a different database, such as CouchDB (Cons: managing
  the two stores and keeping them in sync).
- If you have text, then you need to think more about what kind of graph you're trying to get out of it. Do you want person/place/thing
  information linked together? Then you might check out the GraphAware
  NLP plugins for Neo4j - but they work on the text, not on docs/PDFs.